# How to make sure that calling submit on a JSOUP FormElement, first button is triggered in case that form has 2 buttons with 'submit' type

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

```
<form id="form1">
   <button type="submit" id="btn1">Submit</button>
   <button type="submit" id="btn2">Clear</button>
</form>
```

In above example upon calling, `formElement.submit()` function, I want the click event of button with id '`btn1`' to trigger.
For a more clear understanding, I'm trying to scrape below website:
https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=101
trying to simulate the "Check Status" button click which is in the form with `id = 'form_rcdl'`.
It has 2 buttons with `type = 'submit'`

Java code:

```
Document doc; //getting the html doc for above mentioned page here
form = (FormElement) doc.getElementById("form_rcdl");
Connection post = form.submit();
post.cookies(cookies); //These cookies coming from previous connection
Connection.Response res;
res = post.validateTLSCertificates(false).execute();
Document out = res.parse(); //Need to pass this document further to another function
```